# I have a big problem with my new version 4.2.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, version

When I create a new project after update the new version of android studio, its not generate main activity file & layout folder.. I try to add it manually but its not working.

its my dependencies in `builde.gradle` file

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'

Comment: and what is the error for this failure, can you share that as well